# How to hide the sharethis widget on mobile/handheld devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget, sharethis

I am working on a website  with the sharethis widget when i open the site in handheld devices like mobiles,tablets the sharethis widget hide the contents and disturb to view the site properly. so, i tried the below methods to hide the sharethis widget on handheld devices

Method 1:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var checker = {
        iphone: (ua.indexOf('iphone') >= 0 || ua.indexOf('ipod') >= 0 ||ua.indexOf('ipad') >= 0) ? true : false,
        blackberry: ua.indexOf("blackberry") >= 0 ? true : false,
        android: ua.indexOf("android") >= 0 ? true : false,
        chrome: ua.indexOf("chrome") >= 0 ? true : false,
        nokia: (ua.indexOf("symbian") >= 0 || ua.indexOf('nokia') >= 0) ? true : false
    };

   if (checker.android || checker.iphone || checker.blackberry || checker.nokia) {
       $('#sthoverbuttons').hide();
   }
```

Method 2:

```
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
      $('#sthoverbuttons').hide();
    }
```

Method 3:

```
  if($(window).width() < 980)
   {
      $('#sthoverbuttons').hide();//this one works but i need to find devices and hide.
   }
```

where the  **#sthoverbuttons** is the container for the sharethis widget

And i also tried to remove the script sharethis script's when loading the webpage by assign id to the script tag's but that also not helps me.

So, How to hide the sharethis widget in handheld devices

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with CSS3 media queries. Handheld devices generally are classified to be <600px wide, so adding something like this to your css file should solve your issue:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 599px){
    #sthoverbuttons { display: none; }
}
```

Comment: **make sure you add it to the end of your css file**

Answer (score 0):

You could try [CSS Browser Selector](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/), a small javascript that writes in your `<html>` tag a bunch of classes targeting the current browser and OS, like this:

```
<html class="webkit chrome mac js">
```

meaning I'm on a Mac, using Chrome (Webkit engine), with javascript active.

One of the classes available in CSS Browser Selector is actually `mobile`, so you could target your buttons disregarding the media query on `max-width` that is not conclusive:

```
html.mobile #sthoverbuttons { display: none; }
```